# Magento:Changes in .phtml file have no effect

Tags: php, magento, caching, nginx

Since about three weeks changes on *.phtml* files have no effect on our productive magento installation. Therefore the same changes take effect on our test installation which is essentially a copy of it. Changes are made on the test installation. Thereby I'm following the Template Path Hints. Of course we are using our own template like: `/app/design/frontend/venedor/mod/` We don't modify core, base or default-files. After everything looks fine the changes are transfered to production. Changes are uploaded successfully and downloading again shows the changes. Have doublechecked the Template Path Hints in production, too. Cache has been cleared about a thousand times.

The same with *.php* files. But changes in *.csv* files in `/app/design/frontend/venedor/mod/locale/` take effect.

We are running Magento CE 1.9.2.1 on:

- Linux 2.6.32-openvz-042stab084.17-amd64 (no root-access, no more information)
- nginx 1.9.3
- PHP 5.3.27 +PHP-FPM
- Google PageSpeed is available but disabled

I have absolutely no clue about this behavior... Maybe some kind of caching effect of nginx or PHP-FPM? Any idea or what kind of information I should add?

Comment: do you have APC enabled ? http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: Is enabled, but not that high TTL: `apc.ttl: 48000`, `apc.user_ttl: 48000` (13,3h)

Comment: Restart helps temporarily, but will update as far as I know more.

Comment: restarting FPM u mean ? since this will flush APC

Comment: Right. At least temporarily a solution until we've found the cause the cache is not being released.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending ?abc=def  to the url to see if the page changes. If it does then you know it's caching issue. Do you have Varnish cache on your server?

Comment: We aren't using Varnish.
Don't understand, why to append parameters... All requests are forwarded to index.php like in every SEO-optimized online shop.